# Can I register external JS files on a page via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my CMS I add modules to the page via Javascript, these modules may include external JS files which get registered on page load into a collaborated external file.

When the modules are added via JS these scripts are therefore not registered until the page is reloaded.

Is there a way for me to register these scripts dynamically via the javascript calls in the mean time?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a script tag to your page using the following code:

```
var head  = document.documentElement.childNodes[0];
var sTag  = document.createElement("script");
sTag.src  = "/path/to/script.js";
sTag.type = "text/javascript";
head.appendChild(sTag);
```

You could also use `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]` for the `head` var.  Alternatively, you could use `document.write`, like so:

```
document.write(
    '<script src="path/to/script.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>'
);
```

Comment: Would this actually register the javascript functions though?

Comment: Yes it would however only *after* its downloaded and parsed the file. Its a good idea to have a callback in the bottom of your script which can call a function in your page to let you know when its loaded and ready or you can poll for the existance of a function in your file using setInterval

Comment: Don't use `</scr'+'ipt>'` - it is pointless in an external JS file and invalid in an HTML file. If you want embedded scripts containing that string, use: `<\/script>'`

Comment: Well, they would be registered after the current javascript is parsed, meaning if you reference those functions before they are parsed an error would occur.  To avoid this you would have to delay calling those functions (using either the onload event or a timer with a timeout length of 0).

Comment: @David Dorward, I did explain why the closing script tag was split up. @Pete, you beat me to it :)

Comment: Great thanks, I'll give it a go this afternoon and award answer if all gravy. Im suprised that browsers work like that, would have thought all the functions were added onload or something instead of reparsing the dom

Comment: @Andy E — yes, but you did it wrong. That approach depends on bugs or error recovery in HTML parsers.

Comment: Scripts are parsed by the scripting engine, not the DOM rendering engine, so whenever a new tag is added to the DOM it's just handed to the scripting engine for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following function, inspired by the jQuery's `$.getScript` method, it takes an `url` and a `callback` argument.

The callback is very useful, it is executed when the script has been loaded successfully, and you are ready to use it.

This function also takes care of removing the `script` elements from the DOM to avoid well known [memory leaks](http://ajaxian.com/archives/dynamic-script-generation-and-memory-leaks):

```
loadScript("myLib.js", function () {
  // myLib is loaded
  //..
});

function loadScript(url, callback) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
      script = document.createElement("script"),
      done = false;

  script.src = url;
  // Attach event handlers for all browsers
  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if ( !done && (!this.readyState ||
      this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete") ) {
      done = true;
      callback(); // Execute callback function
      // Prevent memory leaks in IE
      script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
      head.removeChild( script );
    }
  };
  head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Nice function :) Although, I'm not sure I understand what benefit there is with removing the script from the DOM afterwards, wouldn't the contents already be parsed and loaded into memory? What would be gained by removing the element? You've got me curious now! :)

Comment: It's about IE :(, it has problems and starts to leak memory, it needs also the script event handlers (`onload` and `onreadystatechange`) to be nullified in order to garbage collect correctly... IE sucks...

Comment: I've had problems with adding script tags to fetch JSONP (in IE) before and removing the tags caused a huge memory leak each time - each script file could be at least 30k.  I didn't have any event handlers attached, but it was still leaking.  In the end i went back to XMLHttpRequest and bog standard JSON.  But yeah, IE does suck.